# Difference of o and go in NERDTree

Tags: nerdtree

In NERD tree (4.2.0) quickhelp,

```
o: open in prev window
go: preview
```

I tried both of them but I can't find any differences. What are the differences?

Answer (score 5):

- In the NERDTree sidebar if you hit **o** on a file, then the file is opened and cursor is **placed in the file**
- In the NERDTree sidebar if you hit **go** on a file, then the file is opened and cursor **stays in the NERDTree sidebar**. You can **preview** any file at will without moving away from NERDTree.

`o.......Open files, directories and bookmarks....................|NERDTree-o|
go......Open selected file, but leave cursor in the NERDTree.....|NERDTree-go|`

You can find more help [here](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/master/doc/NERDTree.txt#L226).

Hope it helps.